# error: expected primary-expression before 'template' - what am I doing wrong?

Tags: c++, templates, metaprogramming

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

template<class T> struct A {
    A( const std::initializer_list<T> &list ) {
        for( template std::initializer_list<T>::iterator it = list.begin();
             it != list.end(); ++it ) {
            content.emplace( *it );
        }
    }
    ~A() {};
    std::vector<T> content;
};

int main() {
    A<int> a = A<int>( { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 } );
    for( const int x : a.content ) {
        std::cout << x << " ";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The code above reflects a problem I'm having. When I try compiling I get:
`error: expected primary-expression before 'template'...` and 
`error: 'it' was not declared in this scope`
for line 14 (the iterator `for` loop). I've tried some variation but I'm not getting anywhere with them. Does anyone got a clue on this issue? Thanks.

Comment: Replace template with typename in the for loop - that's all :)

Comment: @Keyboard There's also something wrong with `content.emplace(*it)` - [reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/emplace).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. incorrect use of template keyword, suppose to be `typename` or just use `auto`

   for( template std::initializer_list::iterator it = list.begin();
        ^^^^^^^^        it != list.end(); ++it ) {
2. incorrect use `[std::vector::emplace][1]`

The fix is:

```
    for( auto it = list.begin(); it != list.end(); ++it ) 
    {
        content.emplace(content.end(), *it );
    }
```

or:

```
content.insert(content.end(), list);
```

Answer (score 1):

Take out `template` before your definition of `it`

```
for (std::initializer_list<T>::iterator it = list.begin();
            it != list.end(); ++it) {
            content.emplace(*it);
}
```

You are also using the emplace function wrong. [Here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/emplace/) is the documentation for `emplace`